# Mysql - Get all records where there is an equal value in one field and in turn have a non null value in other fields

Tags: mysql, record

Maybe what I'm trying to explain is a bit convoluted, I explain:

I have a table with an imei field, id_factura, id_albaran, transaccion, estado(among others).

An imei can have a `transacion` (compra or venta), and `estado` (nuevo or usado).

In my query I only want it for 'nuevo' ones, in the table there are hundreds of records with imei but there can only be the same imei, estado='nuevo', transaccion='venta' with id_factura not null or/and id_albaran not null.

The objective of this query is to find out if the same imei, transacion=venta,estado=nuevo, has an id_factura record not null and another id_albaran record not null, so I want it to return a field if it has two records with a value of 1 or if it only has one record that return 0.

I give you an example of what I want the query to return, in my case I only want what is marked with red (sale).

[image]

I have tried this(but is wrong):

```
SELECT imei
FROM ventacompra
WHERE transacion = 'venta' AND estado='nuevo' AND id_albaran IS NOT NULL
AND imei IN (SELECT imei FROM ventacompra v WHERE transacion = 'venta' AND estado='nuevo' AND id_factura IS NOT NULL)
```

____EDIT FOR EXAMPLE____

```
transacion     estado   imei   id_factura   id_albaran  has_factu_alba
venta          nuevo    0001        01         NULL       1
venta          nuevo    0001      NULL         01         1
compra         nuevo    0002       01          NULL       0
```

Comment: Is there a case that both id_factura and id_albaran are not null in the same row?

Comment: No, in any case, there always has to be either an id_factura and id_albaran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT v.* FROM ventacompra v
WHERE v.transacion = 'venta' AND v.estado='nuevo' AND (v.id_factura IS NULL XOR v.id_albaran IS NULL)
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM ventacompra
  WHERE  imei = v.imei AND transacion = v.transacion AND estado = v.estado
    AND (id_factura IS NULL) = (v.id_factura IS NOT NULL)
    AND (id_albaran IS NULL) = (v.id_albaran IS NOT NULL)
)
```

If one of the columns `id_factura` and `id_albaran` is always `null` and the other `not null` then you may omit the condition:

```
AND (v.id_factura IS NULL XOR v.id_albaran IS NULL)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/99gmV3w9QYLfQhvLuxzDrJ/3).
Results:

```
| id_ventacompra | transacion | estado | imei            | id_factura | id_albaran |
| -------------- | ---------- | ------ | --------------- | ---------- | ---------- |
| 492            | venta      | nuevo  | 352984109069491 |            | 23         |
| 493            | venta      | nuevo  | 352984109069491 | 10         |            |
```

Comment: Thanks, but the result of this query is empty.

Comment: Thanks again, I have modify your sql editor, you can see:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/99gmV3w9QYLfQhvLuxzDrJ/1

Let's see, I think I have not explained myself correctly, it has to show the records that have a record id_factura and another record id_albaran of the same imei, as you see in the fiddle_sql, if there is a record that is only invoice_id it shows it also and it should not show it, only those that the same imei has a record with id_factura and another record with the same imei id_albaran :)

Comment: I added 1 more condition for `imei`. See my edited answer.

Comment: Now it seems fine, just one last thing and I really appreciate your help, this query then goes into another query as a field, and I need to show this query that you have made it return a 1 instead of the record is it possible?
Thank you

Comment: This query returns 1 or more pairs of rows, so at least 2 rows and not only 1 row. When you say you want it to return 1 what do you mean?

Comment: I have a query in the table vendcompra that is related to other tables, I need a new field that is the query that You have made as a field of that query, for in the case that it contains a record it returns 1 and in the opposite case it returns 0.

Comment: Something like this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/99gmV3w9QYLfQhvLuxzDrJ/4 ?

Comment: More or less, imagine that I want to do a "SELECT id_ventacompra, transacion, estado, imei, id_factura, id_albaran FROM ventacompra" And that there is a new field called "has_factu_alba" (this being the query you have made), so if a record has an imei that is in two more records like imei id_factura and id_albaran show 1 and if it doesn't show 0. Edit main post as example.

Comment: Try this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/99gmV3w9QYLfQhvLuxzDrJ/6

Comment: It works perfect!!! You saved me, you don't know how happy I am now, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by joining to `ventacompra` and matching records with the same `imei`, and then filtering for just the matching records in the `WHERE` clause. Since you're doing a self-join, you also want to `GROUP BY imei` and finally select only the `DISTINCT` results:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT( v1.imei )
FROM
    ventacompra AS v1
LEFT JOIN
    ventacompra AS v2 ON (
        v1.id_ventacompra != v2.id_ventacompra /* avoid joining to self */
            AND
        v1.imei = v2.imei /* match imei */
            AND
        v1.estado = v2.estado AND v1.transaccion = v2.transaccion
    )
WHERE
    v1.transacion = 'venta'
        AND
    v1.estado='nuevo'
        AND
    (
        v1.id_factura IS NOT NULL
            OR
        v2.id_factura IS NOT NULL
    )
        AND
    (
        v1.id_albaran IS NOT NULL
            OR
        v2.id_albaran IS NOT NULL
    )
GROUP BY
    v1.imei
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, friend, but the query you have put back also returns estado='compra, I am going to investigate with the idea that you have proposed and I am saying